# Meteor activating template based on localStorage

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

My Meteor template is arranged like this:

```
<template name="main">
{{#if youwashere}}
{{> content}}
{{#else}}
{{> introduction}}
{{/else}}
{{/if}}
</template>
```

To determine whether a user has been to my site before, I've setup a local storage, which works. I have then tried calling it like this:

```
Template.main.helpers({
youwashere(){ return localStorage.getItem('herebefore'); }
});
```

What is supposed to happen, is this: if there is a localstorage item `('herebefore')` then it would show the template named `content`. But if you did not have that item on your computer, it would show you the template `introduction`. The helper code ends up showing neither, so I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: To store on local storage, I use the following:

```
Template.introduction.events({
'click #button':function(){
localStorage.setItem('herebefore', true);}
});
```

Comment: What value are you storing in localStorage? It should evaluate to "truthy" when returned by `getItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for `else` was simply a bit off:

```
<template name="main">
{{#if youwashere}}
  {{> content}}
{{else}}
  {{> introduction}}
{{/if}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it like so. For whatever reason the else syntax is not working the way I would like it to.

```
<template name="main">
{{#if beenhere}}
{{> currentevents}}
{{/if}}
{{#unless beenhere}}
{{> introduction}}
{{/unless}}
</template>
```